# How to get Calendar setting from Outlook REST API

Tags: outlook, outlook-restapi, outlook-calendar

I was wondering if there is an endpoint where i can find all setting regarding the Calendar in outlook. For example: Calendar color, timezone, notification setting and so on.
I'm using directly the rest api, without any client library.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know these settings are not exposed through REST APIs. You can get some mailbox settings using me/mailboxSettings API but it does not have the properties you are looking for.